# AWS API Gateway- No options for models in Method Response

Tags: httpresponse, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dv4Zx.jpg

Under models, there's no options to choose from for Application/Json content type. I want an empty model for my method response. How do I create this model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a model with empty schema {}. Then you can select that model in method response.

Comment: Where can I create this schema? I dont see an option in API Gateway

Comment: See api gateway documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-create-model.html